# Stylesheet does not load after using RewriteRule and include

Tags: php, html, css, mod-rewrite

I have a website that has an index.php, a few simple .html pages and one .php page (contact form) as well as a .htaccess file. On my website I have buttons that point to the pages as follows: `index.php?p=welcome.php` (example). As you can see, the `index.php` file `includes` a page, depending on what was passed on by `GET`.

I've written the .htaccess to show: `http://www.site.com/welcome/` instead of `http://www.sites.com/index.php?p=welcome`. The links and rewrite both work. The only problem I have is when I click one of the buttons to navigate to another page: there is no styling whatsoever.

I've tested to see if the `index.php` file is including the other pages properly, and it does. It's just the stylesheet that doesn't seem to work. The `style.css` is included at the top of the `index.php` file, where it belongs.  Here are bits of code I'd like to show you:

**Buttons**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/welcome/"><div>Welcome</div></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/references/"><div>References</div></td></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/aboutme/"><div>About me</div></td></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/contact/"><div>Contact</div></td></a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

To make it clear: the site still functions as it normally does, but it just does not apply any styling from the stylesheet. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you navigate to a seperate page, is any of the index.php source involved in the second page, or is this a clean page(redirect)?

Comment: Whats the Url for stylesheets ? is it index.php?p=style.css ? or thats a Plain url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the stylesheet is being included using a relative path, then that would be the problem.  Try using: `/path/to/style.css` rather than `relative/path/to/style.css`

So if your stylesheet lives in `templates/style.css` and you reference it as such, when you rewrite the URL `http://www.site.com/index.php?page=welcome` to `http://www.site.com/welcome/`, the stylesheet's path is relative to that:

`http://www.site.com/welcome/templates/style.css`

Comment: That's it. I'm including the stylesheet using a relative path: `<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. I've changed it to: `/style.css` and now it works perfectly. I guess I still have to learn some more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be including it with a relative path? When your'e using ./ you are trying to include something from the new (non excistent?) /welcome dir.

Try to include your stuff trough the complete path, or use some sort of variable that tells you the real basepath.