# rewriting url using .htaccess for php

Tags: php, .htaccess

When i was trying to rewrite url using .htaccess i got my page css disturbed. i don't know why that happened. Anyone please help..

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

here is the example
[Without rewriting url](http://dreameducation.in/index.php?field=1)

[with rewrite rule](http://dreameducation.in/field/1)

Comment: Your link is broken, but most likely, you are using a relative path for your CSS style sheet. Use an absolute path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stylesheet does not load after using RewriteRule and include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596044/stylesheet-does-not-load-after-using-rewriterule-and-include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS source is relative to the current document.

Make sure, its an absolute URL.. since

in case of rewrite, its requesting, field/stylesheets/style.css instead of stylesheets/style.css

your css source should be :

```
<link href="http://[yoururlhere]/stylesheets/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: should i give all links absolute eg. for javascript files etc.

Comment: Yes, thats the best practice.

Comment: is there any way to give links relative to root ??

Comment: No, if you want to reference a file from the root of your webserver it must start with `/`. Using a dot before the slash `./` makes the reference relative to the current html document. Also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891775/mod-rewrite-url-info-required/891785#891785)

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are broken. Give the absolute path for the css and put one .htaccess file in css directory with only

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

in it