# .htaccess doesn't rewrite relative to the root directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried to create an .htaccess file to do following:

Direct `www.domain.com/name` or `www.domain.com/name/` to `www.domain.com/page.php?id=name`

and `www.domain.com/name/2` or `www.domain.com/name/2/` to `www.domain.com/page.php?id=name&pg=2`

my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # If the request is not for a valid link
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_\.]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_\.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1&pg=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem is, that when I actually use a slash after `name` it thinks of it as a directory and looks for pages in `www.domain.com/name/`.. But I am still able to `$_GET` the variables based on `id` and `pg`.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong? I prefer that the URL in the address bar stays clean as `www.domain.com/name/2/`.

Also i have another question.. I have tried to rewrite the other URLS without luck.

If they write: `www.domain.com/page.php?id=name&pg=2` and want to change the address bar URL to be be clean again, but that completely went wrong for me. Is there any specific way to do this by using what I have already made?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

The solution was based on PHP and not .htaccess. The answer was found based on this question: [Stylesheet does not load after using RewriteRule and include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596044/stylesheet-does-not-load-after-using-rewriterule-and-include) . My problem was caused by PHP including relative to the public URL and directory. I have been forced to define a main URL variable to place before any foreign includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to the very next `RewriteRule`.

Have your code this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1&pg=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't know that.. :) Unfortunately it still seems to look for a directory when I include in PHP.. Perhaps it is something with PHP? Does php include based on the public URL? Cause when I write `/name/2/` then the include requests seems to be based on that directory path.. Also another question. Why do you have `[QSA]` after the second RewriteRule but not the third, when there is still a query string attached?

Comment: Sorry I missed `QSA` from last rule. And yes PHP include are relative to the current directory but I'm not PHP expert.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. do you also know how to rewrite the URL the other way around? so `www.domain.com/page.php?id=name&pg=2` becomes `www.domain.com/name/2/` in the address bar only?

Comment: I have tried but somehow it didn't work at all and I got some pretty weird results :)

Comment: Sure I have added a rule that does `www.domain.com/page.php?id=name&pg=2 => www.domain.com/name/2/`